# Why do the color of my buttons depend on my active window state (tkinter GUI, macOS)?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, colors

I am trying to make a basic chessboard GUI using tkinter in Python. I am running this through VSC. There is not much code to my application, but what seems to be happening is that I set the background color of my buttons to be a certain color as determined by my code and the code works just fine....when my application window is not active. The moment my application window is not active, the color of the buttons revert back to the default grey color.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

# SIMPLE GUI ------------------------------------------------------------

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0, relief="solid",padx=10,pady=10)
frame.grid()

# Button
btns = [[0] * 8 for i in range(8)]

# scales up and down buttons
scale = 0.7
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        if ((i%2 == 0)&(j%2 == 0))|((i%2 == 1)&(j%2 == 1)):
            bgn = "white"
        else:
            bgn = "brown"
        btn = Button(frame, text="Wut", width=int(scale*10), height=int(scale*8), bd=0, highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0, highlightbackground=bgn, activebackground="blue", bg=bgn)
        btns[i][j] = btn
        btn.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew", padx=0, pady=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to set active background color of the buttons, the setting the color of buttons at the very end of the to ensure there are no window events that might interfere with the code, but to no avail. I have tried replicating this problem in replit.com, and there seemed to be no issues there, but I was not sure how they handled active and inactive windows there. Based on the Replit behavior, I guess that there might be a potential problem within macOS exclusively, but I don't have a solid reasoning behind that.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88409) and [this](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/46274a117823fd65c6d98d38465b43165d0c4680). What about trying [CustomTkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter)?